# FieldError at /shop/process_payment/ Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field. Choices are: address, amount, email, items_json, name, order_id, phone

Tags: python, django, django-paypal

- I am using with Django 2.1.5 and Python 3.5
- I want to add paypal payment gateway integration to my project but i
  faced this problem Cannot resolve keyword 'id' into field. Choices
  are: address, amount etc

  **def checkout(request):**

  ```
  if request.method == "POST":

      items_json = request.POST.get('itemsjson', '')
      name     = request.POST.get('name', '')
      amount     = request.POST.get('amount', '')
      email    = request.POST.get('email', '')
      address  = request.POST.get('address1', '') + " " + request.POST.get('address2', '')
      city     = request.POST.get('city', '')
      state    = request.POST.get('state', '')
      zip_code = request.POST.get('zip_code', '')
      phone    = request.POST.get('phone', '')
      order = Orders(items_json=items_json, name=name, amount=amount, email=email, address=address, city=city, state=state, zip_code=zip_code, phone=phone)
      order.save()
      update = OrderUpdate(order_id=order.order_id, update_desc="The order has been placed")
      update.save()
      thank = True
      id = order.order_id
      return redirect('process_payment')
  return render(request, 'shop/checkout.html', locals())
  ```

**def process_payment(request):**

```
order_id = request.session.get('order.order_id')
order = get_object_or_404(Orders, id=order_id)
host = request.get_host()

paypal_dict = {
    'business': settings.PAYPAL_RECEIVER_EMAIL,
    'amount': str(amount),
    'item_name': name,
    'invoice': str(order.order_id),
    'currency_code': 'USD',
    "notify_url": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('paypal-ipn')),
    "return": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('payment_done')),
    "cancel_return": request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('payment_cancelled')),
```

}

```
form = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict)
context = {"form": form}
return render(request, "shop/process_payment.html", context)
```

**my models.py file**

class Orders(models.Model):

```
order_id   = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
items_json = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
amount     = models.IntegerField(default=0)
name       = models.CharField(max_length=90)
email      = models.CharField(max_length=120)
address    = models.CharField(max_length=120)
city       = models.CharField(max_length=120)
state      = models.CharField(max_length=120)
zip_code   = models.CharField(max_length=120)
phone      = models.CharField(max_length=120)
```

class OrderUpdate(models.Model):

```
update_id  = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
order_id   = models.IntegerField(default="")
update_desc = models.CharField(max_length=5000)
timestamp   = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: can you add your whole error message please, so that I can see at which line and on what model you get that error. Your Order and OrderUpdate models as well.

Comment: Sir i edit my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your primary key field of Orders Model is not `id` , use `pk` :

```
order = get_object_or_404(Orders, pk=order_id)
```

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/process_payment

Comment: sir i used your solution but now show me this error

Comment: ensure order_id has been saved as pk, then check that value of order_id in session is same with it